# How to change windows theme (or at least the background) using the command line or scripts

Tags: scripting, windows-10, autohotkey

I am trying to make it so that the theme (or at least the background) changes when I switch desktop view. I have found some answers but most if not all are about old versions of windows and do not work for windows 10. The scripting tool I am using is AHK. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know it's possible with C#
[#UWP Tips: C# code to change #Windows 10 Start Screen image](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2015/10/uwp-start-screen.html#vXcTCAH1IjPAEcl2.97)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible to change the background using this command:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  wallpaper_path /f
```

Changing the theme is not that direct, you might want to run the following command. What it does is that it will show you a dialog where you can pick the theme you want. (It may also reset your theme to default)

```
rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:"C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero.theme"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's although possible to change the theme using this command:

```
call <path-to-your-theme>
```

You close the opened window using this command:

```
taskkill /IM ApplicationFrameHost.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while looking to do the same thing for my company's computer image. The command below worked well for me, keep in mind that the `taskkill` part would kill all settings windows

`C:\PATH\TO\THEME\FILE.theme & timeout /t 03 /nobreak > NUL & taskkill /f /im systemsettings.exe`

This will launch the theme file which will apply the theme but also open the Setting app/window, but then it will wait for the timeout (set to 3 seconds in the command above) then kill the Settings app/window. Tested on Windows 10 Enterprise x64 v1909. Also depending on the performance of the computers you might be able to lower the timeout from 3 seconds.

Martin's answer didnt work for me, but after some reading it believe its because of changes made with either v1809 or v1903